# Is it safe to use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` in a signal handler?

Tags: c++, c++11, signal-handling

I know it is not safe for `malloc` or `free` to be called, directly or indirectly, from a signal handler.

But, if I can guarantee that at least one shared reference will remain alive, is it then safe to copy-construct and destruct additional shared or weak references, or do I have to roll my own refcounting?

(Yes, I know signal handlers *usually* shouldn't do much. But I have a good reason this time.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard defines the concept of a "plain old function" as follows:

> A POF (“plain old function”) is a function that uses only features from [the C/C++] common subset, and that does not directly or indirectly use any function that is not a POF, except that it may use plain lock-free atomic operations.

Furthermore:

> The behavior of any function other than a POF used as a signal handler in a C++ program is implementation-defined.

Obviously, C++ class objects are not part of the C/C++ common subset, and therefore using them in a signal handler yields implementation-defined behavior.

Now, many implementations will allow you limited usage of C++ features. If your implementation doesn't permit memory allocations or exceptions, then here's what we know about those smart pointer types.

Then all [`weak_ptr` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr) are explicitly declared `noexcept`. So they can't throw exceptions. This also means that they're not allowed to allocate memory (since failing to allocate memory would throw an exception). Yes, they could allocate memory and `std::terminate` if it fails, but that would be exceedingly rude for an implementation to do.

The [copy&move constructors of `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) similarly is `noexcept`, so the same applies. This is also true for the aliasing constructor for `shared_ptr`.

If you are *absolutely certain* that at least one `shared_ptr` will still exist, then destroying a `shared_ptr` is explicitly stated to not have side effects. Which probably includes memory de-allocations.

Those are the guarantees that the standard library gives you.